# JQuery mobile forces GET on browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery mobile 1.4.2 and Django 1.6 for the backend. This is my problem:

I have a total of 3 very simple pages linked to 3 distinct Django views:

```
Page A -> Search form.
Page B -> Results page (gets the POST from A and displays the results as a <table>)
Page C -> Shows a customized page based on what was clicked on page B. 
(i.e. http://example.com?id=a44)
```

Every page has a navigation bar which contains a back button. The problem is that when I'm on page C and then press the **back button** (*either the navbar's or the browser's native one*), the system calls `GET` on page B instead of going back in browser history. This can create all sorts of problems.

I also have no custom css in neither of the 3 pages. This is how I implement the navbar's back button:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">BACK</a>
```

Please note that if I put `data-ajax="false"` on the form of page A the problem goes away but at the cost of the jquery transitions. Is there a way I can "fix" this and keep the transitions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you retrieve results and call page B?

Comment: @Omar Using a Django view via request.POST. i.e. `id=request.POST['productID']`. Then I call page B template using the render() method.

Comment: a "fix" is to change page programmatically by attaching a listener to back button. But i dont know (need to test it) how it will act on browser's back button.

Comment: @Omar Fair enough. How should I do this? Given that I am a begginer in javascript/jquery could you possibly provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hnhq7/

Comment: @Omar Unfortunately that doesn't work. Is there any other way we force ajax to keep state?